# How can I translate custom taxonomies in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, translation, taxonomy

I am wondering if there is any way to translate wordpress custom taxonomies on the frontend?

My idea is to intercept the rendering of taxonomies at some point (at my functions.php) and then render the translated strings which are stored in an array or JSON or txt file. I prefer not to use any plugin.

Your comments and and answers are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('get_term', 'change_term_name_at_front', 10, 2);

function change_term_name_at_front($term, $taxonomy) {
    //only for frontend
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $term;
    }
    
   $new_names_array = array(
    "taxonomy_id" => "New name",
    "taxonomy_id2" => "New name2",
   );
   

   if ($taxonomy == 'your_taxonomy_name') {

            $new_name = $new_names_array[$term->term_id];

            if ($new_name !="") {
                $term->name = $new_name;
            }
        
   }

    return $term;
}
```

If you already have ACF plugin, you can add an additional field to the taxonomy and write there the new name, instead of using an array.

```
add_filter('get_term', 'change_term_name_at_front', 10, 2);

function change_term_name_at_front($term, $taxonomy) {
    //only for frontend
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $term;
    }

   if ($taxonomy == 'your_taxonomy_name') {

            $key_field_acf = "yourtax_" . $term->term_id; 

            $new_name = get_field( 'new_name', $key_field_acf );

            if ($new_name !="") {
                $term->name = $new_name;
            }

   }

    return $term;
}
```

Comment: Amazing! it works. Thank you.

Comment: sorry I cant up vote for your answer. It is my first question on stackoverflow and I still dont have minimum reputation to vote.

Comment: I just installed ACF and did as you said. It worked perfectly. The second method is far better because i will avoid playing around the code. Thanks again.